# header refresh in div with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a login.php file:

```
if(...) {
  ...
header('Refresh: 1; url="login.php"';
} else {
echo '<form name="submit">...</form>';
}
```

and code with jquery:

```
$('#resetreq').live('submit', function() {
    $.post('login.php', $(this).serialize(), function (
            data, textStatus) {
        $('#resetPwDiv').html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

and , where to show the form. how to put work refresh with javascript that refreshes in the div? I want to refresh once after submit pressing.

Thank you for responses.

Comment: Btw what's the point of using live() instead of straight submit() function? Just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

You m8 want use function variable event, and then use predefined function event.preventDefault(); to make your submit not redirect to php page.

```
$('#resetreq').live('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('login.php', $(this).serialize(), function (
            data, textStatus) {
        $('#resetPwDiv').html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: .live() has been depreciated.

Comment: Hehe read my other comment down the main post :) I just included my solution inside his script without modyfing everything, thanks for concern tho.

Comment: .on()-function does not work. I have the php-file like
if(..) {}

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: Also your PHP has nothing to do with JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: .on()-function does not work. I have the php-file like
if(..) {
  echo "Pleace wait, if you are being log in...";
  header("refresh: 5;url='login.php'");
} else {
  echo "<form>..</form>"
}
I want to show the "Pleace wait, if you are being log in" in the div 5 seconds and after then automticaly the form. How to put works correctly and with .on() function?

Answer (score 0):

Due to .live being deprecated, you should use .on():

```
$(element).on('submit', function(e){...})
```

If you need to listen for events on content generated by AJAX, you can do it like so:

```
$(document).on('submit','#resetreq', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    $.post('login.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
        $('#resetPwDiv').html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Where can I find a list of all deprecated functions in jQuery?

Comment: You can find a list by going to google and searching "deprecated jQuery functions"

Answer (score 0):

In jquery we can refresh the div by using this one

$("#divId").load(location.href + " #divId>*", "");